# Can I configure HTML Purifier to allow <style> tags?

Tags: htmlpurifier

How do I allow `<style>` tags in [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)?

Answer (score 3):

Install CSSTidy and hook it up to Filter.ExtractStyleBlocks http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Filter.ExtractStyleBlocks

You'll need a story on the calling code to get the style block contents to somewhere appropriate.